# Regarding SQL instances in Goolge Cloud, is it possible to delete specific data in a backup?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, database-backups

I've looked at deleting SQL backups in the Google Cloud documentation, although I do not want to delete my entire backup: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/backups/delete

I have two questions, I hope someone can help me with, or perhaps guide me to someone who might be able to help me.

One: The SQL backups in Google Cloud are incremental, but is it possible to delete a specific inscrement?

Two: Is it possible to delete specific data on a specific increment? Let's say I added two people, Tom and Bob, to one of my data sets. This would later be backed up. I know it is possible to delete Tom from my live data set, but would it be possible to delete Tom from the backup also? Without deleting the entire backup?

Comment: The answer to both of your questions if no. I this was possible, nobody would trust backups.

Comment: If your concern is about GDPR (or any regulation that require to delete users when  they ask), it's common to delete hot data quickly (48h) and then to mention in the confirmation email that the backup data will be delete in the next 30 days. To let time to rotate the backup and to delete the obsolete ones that contains the effective data to remove.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a [specific](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backing-up#deleting_a_backup) on-demand/automatic backup from the Google Cloud SQL. Since the backups are incremental, so deleting the backup doesn't free as much space as the size of the backup and for data consistency/integrity purpose after deletion of old backup might transfer it's content to it a recent backup. A backup has been automatically created after being crated a SQL instance and at this stage if you take multiple backup it will be an incremental backup. However, if you deleted the first automatic backup, it will transfer the data to most recent incremental backup. You can see the backup list from Cloud SQL > Backups > List of all backup. Yes, you can delete any backup any specific time.

For your second question, I'm agreed with @John Hanley. Backup files are kept in a special format that only readable by database engine while you restore the data. It's not possible to modify the content of backup file. If someone want to modify the file, it will be corrupted.